# Ubuntu 15.04 won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04

I have just completed a fresh install of ubuntu 15.04. Everything seemed successful, but when I boot I get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I installed it on an ssd drive (/dev/sda) [image]

I tried to reinstall grub2 but it did not work:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda

update-grub

exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

but the problem still exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I looked over this but the fixes seem to be if you can get into the grub menu. I can't even get that far. I should not that I am using a Nvidia graphics card (gtx780)

Comment: I have tried to set nomodeset in the grub file as well but the problem still persists.

Comment: You need to boot with `nomodeset` using grub menu, then install the driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is on /dev/sda1.
This is the extended partition ... AS A WHOLE ...
So therefore it looks like the boot flag should be on /dev/sda5 not /dev/sda1

Comment: Thanks this was it. So simple can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much